# Changing label of views exposed date filter select list

Tags: datetime, views

Trying to change the label of a views exposed date filter based on Year granularity which is a select list. I have given date range to the filter thus it does not generate the "#options" array.

It creates a dropdown with year values and a "-Year" to display all values.

I want to rename this "-Year" label. Could not find any options within the view to change this label. So is there any hook or alter that can be used here ?

[image]

Yes i am using Better exposed filter and trying to use Date filter based on Content Post Date. After applying BEF i get a select list to the exposed date filter. I need to change the "-Year" label inside this dropdown. tried using hook_form_alter but not able to search this label and change it.

[image]

Attached a screenshot of the settings page for the Date filter. And under BEF settings I selected the Default select list option. Could not find any way to rename the "-Year" label.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can put a screen shot for your filter configuration, also make sure if there is configuration to do at better exposed filter level. I doubt why label can't be changed from the view itself, still if want to try it with the code hook_form_alter() should help you as exposed filter is also a form.

Comment: I have attached the screenshots and updated my question.

Comment: How did you add your dropdown? Try to look in Date filter settings there should be settings for your dropdown if it

Comment: Updated the question with settings page snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is something we have already on drupal issue-queue as https://www.drupal.org/node/2296607.

I was expecting the options to be alterable by any hook, unfortunately could not find any.

I explored the code in date module, and found the elements are processed by a function as [date_parts_element](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!date!date_api!date_api_elements.inc/function/date_parts_element/7), under which it appending '-' before the label.

Now, while the following will fix your issue but I would nor recommend it to you until it is approved by community. The hack is

In your date_api_elements.inc file(date/date_api) inside function `date_parts_element` add this line `drupal_alter('date_process_element', $sub_element);` in the bottom just before `return $element;` so it looks as

```
    ..... 
    if ($element['#date_label_position'] == 'within') {
      $sub_element['ampm']['#options'] = array('' => '-' . $label) + $sub_element['ampm']['#options'];
    }
  }
  drupal_alter('date_process_element', $sub_element);
  return $sub_element;
}
```

This will allow any custom module to alter the elements of date filter. Now in your custom module let's say named as my_module implement the hook we have added as following

```
/**
  * Implements hook_date_process_element_alter.
 */
function my_module_views_date_process_element_alter(&$element) {
  foreach($element['year']['#options'] as $key=>$value) {
    if($value == '-Year') {
        $element['year']['#options'][$key] = 'Year';// Or whatever you like to give.
    }
  }
}
```

I will be adding the same suggestion on drupal issue page.

**Update**

Indeed no patch required, date module provides the hooks out of the box, got to know from update mentioned issue feeds, didn't try the cpde myself but looks promising

```
function MYMODULE_date_select_process_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context) {
  // Tweak the -Year filter to remove the -
  if (empty($element['year'])) return;
  foreach ($element['year']['#options'] as $key => $value) {
    if ($value == '-Year') {
      $element['year']['#options'][$key] = 'Select Year';
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Until it gets approved my the community wont use this hack and will prefer changing it by jQuery instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in the template.php file

```
if ($form_id == "views_exposed_form"){
$form['your field_value']['#options']['All'] = t('your word');// overrides <All> on the dropdown }
```